# Самоучение на Java

Tags: java, многопоточность, потоки-данных, коллекции

Сейчас готовлюсь к интервью, которое будет через неделю, и на сколько мне известно в той компании очень любят задавать каверзные вопросы на различные Java SE темы, третью неделю вникаю(углубленно) в коллекции, исключения, потоки, синтаксис, обьекты и наследования, но чувствую что крыша едет от постоянного чтения, хочется практики чтоб закрепить, буду признателен если кто то сможет порекомендовать альтерантивный способ достижения сатори ну или практическое задание. Мой уровень Junior, опыт около полу года, задачки по типу сортирвок, рекурсий, числ фибоначчи не интересны, это я уже давно прошел. Хочу глубже копнуть в потоки, коллекции, И\О.

Comment: ...эм...ну практика и только практика...смотреть исходники..въезжать...потоки и коллекции сами по себе не сложны, тем более в Java.
В принципе из коллекций: ArrayList, HashMap, HashSet, ну потоки нужно просто помнить и понимать синхронизацию...В двух словах конечно не рассказать. Но я думаю на уровень Junior с Вас особо взять нечего. Лично по своему опыту, могу сказать, что работодателя интересует больше фрэймворки, даже не столько знание, сколько понимание
а так в кратце:
http://habrahabr.ru/post/132241/
http://habrahabr.ru/post/162017/
http://habrahabr.ru/post/164487/
+SQL без него никуда

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Попробуйте реализовать элементы функционального программирования. Для примера возьмите C#. Сделайте [предикаты](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfcke1bz.aspx), создайте свои коллекции, реализующие хотя-бы часть из того, что умеет [`List` из C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx). Для начала `Find`, `FindAll`, `ForEach`, что-то из методов расширения (`Where`, `Max`, `Sum` и т. п.). Напишите свои `Map` и `Reduce`. Сделайте эти методы "[ленивыми](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)" и, по возможности, параллельными. Для предикатов попробуйте реализовать [каррирование](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5).

Задача, безусловно, нетривиальная, но поможет прокачать свои скилы. Для вдохновения можете глянуть на бибилиотеку [Functional Java](http://functionaljava.org/).

Comment: 1 - почемуC#
2 - зачем?)

Comment: 1. Дело вкуса. Мне лично очень нравятся подобные фишки для шарповских коллекций.

  2. Just for fun) Автор хотел попрактиковаться с коллекциями и потоками - я предложил нетривиальную задачу, которая потребует знаний и того, и другого.

Comment: 1. просто вопрос вроде о Java
2. Коллекции, не лучшее место для велосипедостроения, как минимум для этого стоит:
2.1. прочесть и осознать Кнута
2.2. Знать как работает Java, чтобы сделать что-то более оптимальное, чем предложеное.

Лично я считаю, что лучше выполнять более прикладные задачи, например: прочесть текстовый файл и зипахть его в БД, например. больше толку будет

Comment: 1. Ответ тоже про Java. Если опустить подробности, то мой ответ звучал так: "реализуйте на Java крутую фишку из C#"

  2. Задачу написать это оптимально я не ставил. Для нчала можно написать так, чтобы оно просто работало, затем, если будет желание, копать глубже.

Да, базы данных это важно и полезно. Я согласен с вашим комментом к вопросу - фреймворки нужно знать хотя бы поверхностно. Я просто предложил интересную задачу для самосовершеннствования.

Comment: эм...и фана ради..я Ваш подход не оспариваю, каждому свое интересно...просто время потратит, а результата не много..+ схожие фишки есть в Java. Просто на интервью, через неделю, это не оценят)

Comment: спасибо огромное, звучит очень интересно, займемся!

Answer (score 3):

Я бы на Вашем месте глянул бы на многообразие Open Source проектов и выбрал какой-либо по душе себе. Нашел бы н а страничке проекта багтрекер и открыв его начал наслаждаться тем что помогаю людям и решаю конкретные боевые задачи.

Comment: я считаю себя недостаточно опытным для такого, но почему бы не попробовать, спасибо!